# ffmpeg imlib2.so : watermarked video file size is way bigger than the original and without sound!

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

```
ffmpeg -sameq -i '/var/www/original.flv' -vhook '/usr/lib/vhook/imlib2.so \
       -x 0 -y 0 -i /var/www/watermark.jpg' /var/www/out/after.flv
```

The watermark.jpg is a small text under 5kb.  After i run it, after.flv is 90mb.  Original.flv is only 40mb!  Why such large difference?

And there is no sound in the after.flv! the video quality is same though!  When i dont use -sameq, after.flv is way too small, and video quality is very poor. also without sound!!!!

Comment: It might help if you show us the complete output of ffmpeg.  Please edit your question with the ffmpeg output.

Comment: You are not alone.I have the same problem. Maybe it is because of -sameq. You can try -vcodec copy and -acodec copy.